# Could I fix the -1 in the EliminateDuplicates method?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, duplicates

Problem: Eliminate duplicates

Write a method that returns a new array by eliminating the duplicate values in the array using the following method header:

public static int[] eliminateDuplicates (int[] list)

Write a program that reads in ten integers, invokes the method, and displays the result.

I am trying to remove the -1s in my java code. I figured out the first part but i’m confusing myself on how to fix my eliminateDuplicates method. I was told to add “int[] list2 = new int[count]” Can anyone give me advice on how to fix this. I am still very new to coding

```
public class Lab09 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter ten numbers: ");
        int[] num = new int[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
            num[i] = s.nextInt();
        }
        num = eliminateDuplicates(num);

        System.out.print("The distinct numbers are: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(num[i] + " ");
        }
        s.close();
    }

    public static int[] eliminateDuplicates(int[] list) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            for (int v = i + 1; v < list.length; v++) {
                if (list[i] == list[v]) {
                    list[v] = -1;
                }
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: You tagged `javascript` but use `java` in your question; which is it?

Comment: Java, i will remove javascript for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

This is not the most efficient solution, but one way would be to create a method `removeInvalidData`, that:

1. Orders the data to have the invalid data (`-1`) at the beginning or end of the array
2. Counts the amount of invalid data
3. Creates a new array of the size of the valid data (total data count - invalid data count)
4. Fills the new array with the valid data

An example for this would be:

```
private static int[] removeInvalidNumbers(int[] numbers) {
    int numberOfInvalidData = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < numbers.length; j++) {
            if (numbers[i] < numbers[j]) {
                int temp = numbers[i];
                numbers[i] = numbers[j];
                numbers[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] == -1) {
            numberOfInvalidData++;
        }
    }
    
    int[] newNumbers = new int[numbers.length - numberOfInvalidData];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < newNumbers.length; i++) {
        newNumbers[i] = numbers[i];
    }
    
    return newNumbers;
}
```

You would call this function in the `return` statement of `eliminateDuplicates`:

```
return removeInvalidNumbers(list);
```

As you can see, it uses multiple `for-loops` even nested ones multiple times.

---

I like this approach better:

1. Creates a new array that has the non duplicated numbers in it `nonDuplicatedNumbers`
2. Creates a flag for `isDuplicate` that tells us if the number is duplicated
3. Adds the number to `nonDuplicatedNumber` if `isDuplicate` is false
4. Counts the number of invalid data at the same time
5. Calls the function to remove invalid data

   ```
    private static int[] eliminateDuplicates(int[] list) {
        int[] nonDuplicatedNumbers = new int[list.length];
        int numberOfDuplicates = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            boolean isDuplicate = false;
            for (int j = 0; j < nonDuplicatedNumbers.length; j++) {
                if (list[i] == nonDuplicatedNumbers[j]) {
                    isDuplicate = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!isDuplicate) {
                nonDuplicatedNumbers[i - numberOfDuplicates] = list[i];
            } else {
                numberOfDuplicates++;
            }
        }

        nonDuplicatedNumbers = removeInvalidData(nonDuplicatedNumbers, numberOfDuplicates);

        return nonDuplicatedNumbers;
    }
   ```

And now `removeInvalidData` does the following:

1. Creates a new array of the size of the valid data (total - invalid data counts)
2. Iterates over the array using the new array's length to store the non duplicated values
3. Returns the non duplicated numbers

   ```
    private static int[] removeInvalidData(int[] numbers, int numberOfDuplicates) {
        int[] validNumbers = new int[numbers.length - numberOfDuplicates];

        for (int i = 0; i < validNumbers.length; i++) {
            validNumbers[i] = numbers[i];
        }

        return validNumbers;
    }
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much for all the advice and steps, i just have a question, could this code be possible without a boolean?

Comment: @alana Why would you want to do it without a boolean? It's much simpler this way. You could try modifying this code but I'm not going to try and come up with a more complex solution

Comment: i was just curious if it was possible, thats all

Comment: @alana it might be possible but it would require much more thinking, and would make the solution much more complex